# Upload parameter values using file

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My customer wants to upload list of values using a file and wants the report to display results based on the uploaded values.

Is it possible to upload a file to SSRS and get the report?

My query would be like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME 
WHERE COLUMN IN ('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR' /*, etc */ )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a datasource query an xml file: determine the columns included, and set a parameter's values based on the results. Then columns or rows could be excluded or included based on the parameter. That gets you a pure SSRS solution.

But if I were designing for simliar requirements, I would set up an SSIS package to import the file into a table in the database, then write SQL in the report to filter down to the appropriate values.

The dataset for a report needs to have a stable set of fields, so you'll need to use a matrix style report to vary the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

What you can do is read this file and create the report URL concatenating the original URL with `&parameter1=value&parameter2=value` and so on, where parameter1 is the name of your parameter and value, the value

and in the end you can add `&rc:parameters=False` so the parameters tool bar wont be visible