# import data from .txt for reporting purposes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, crystal-reports, reportbuilder3.0

I am running a query in Report builder that uses order numbers (approx. 100). Currently they are fixed and I have to change them each time. Is there a way that I can import those numbers to Report Builder in .txt and then run the report.

The query is like the following:

```
Select * from purchase p
where p.order in ('15642','1245','623565')
```

This is a simple query but my query has lots of joins

If not, how can I rewrite this report so that users can choose their own order number? 
Does Cyrstal report have that ability?
Making a .Net/C# application Tool and export results to EXCEL??

Suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS Report - Upload parameter values using file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284563/ssrs-report-upload-parameter-values-using-file)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Crystal Reports can import from textfiles (At least Crystal Reports XI that I'm using), although that functionality might not be installed by default.

Create a new connection, choose "Access/Excel (DAO)". In the dialog that comes up, select "Text" as database type. By default the first line of the text file is supposed to be headers. I don't know if it is possible to change this behaviour.

As for letting users choose the order number at runtime that is precicely what parameters are for. Create a parameter and call it like `{CR_test_txt.TEST0001} = {?myParameter}` in the field selection expert. Depending on your report and advanced runtime options you want you might have to parse the parameter before using it.